# trying to retrieve a list of categories from firebase database ( swift )

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a list of categories from firebase. but the issue is that I'm also retrieving the name of the parent.

[image]

[image]

```
//initiate downloading categories from database

    self.downloadCategoriesFromDatabase()
    //


}

---------------------custom function downlaods--------------------------------

    //  custom function downlaods categories from firebase
    func downloadCategoriesFromDatabase(){

        //   call to the root of the database and downlaod a snapshot
        refCategories.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            //  check if "categories" exist. if yes we proceed to downlaod
            if snapshot.hasChild("Categories") {



----------------- //  get each item in the snapshot and add category name to categories array



              self.refCategories.child("Categories").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in


                    self.categories.removeAll()

                    let enumerator = snapshot.children
                    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                        self.categories.append(rest.key)
                    }

--------------------  // add downloaded categories to  array


                     self.categories.append(snapshot.key)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {



                        //  let's reload tableview
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }


                }
                }

            //   reload the table view if the category is not available
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last `self.categories.append(snapshot.key)` to get rid of that `Categories` item.

In general though your code looks rather complex for what it's trying to do. As far as I can see, this would do the same:

```
func downloadCategoriesFromDatabase(){

    self.refCategories.child("Categories").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        self.categories.removeAll()

        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            self.categories.append(rest.key)
        }

        self.tableview.reloadData()

    }

}
```

If gets rid of the nested listener, the double way of reload, and the extra key you had in there.

Comment: it worked, thank you for taking the time out  to help